# Rails - How to loop through db table column where row value is 'x' and display in html table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, html-table

This is a bit hard to explain so I'll map it out

This is an example of the db table

```
    Table - Items
-----------------------
| name | key  | value |
-----------------------
| n1   | k1   |  12   |
-----------------------
| n1   | k2   |  32   |
-----------------------
| n1   | k3   |  22   |
-----------------------
| n2   | k1   |  56   |
-----------------------
| n2   | k2   |  34   |
-----------------------
| n2   | k3   |  11   |
-----------------------
```

The DB table is simplified to keep the post short and i cant change the way the DB is setup (it would make my life easier but i cant)

I need the data to be looped through and displayed like below where the 'value' associated with the 'key' is in the table.

```
| Name   |   k1   |  k2  | k3   |
---------------------------------
|  n1    |   12   |  32  | 22   |
---------------------------------
|  n2    |   56   |  34  | 11   |
---------------------------------
```

For the table I've tried

```
<table id="example" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>k1</th>
      <th>k2</th> 
      <th>k3</th>   
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  <%  @items.each do |item| %>
    <tr>
                           <td><%= item.name %></td>
    <% if item.key == 'k1' %> <td><%= item.value %></td> <% end %>
    <% if item.key == 'k2' %> <td><%= item.value %></td> <% end %>
    <% if item.key == 'k3' %> <td><%= item.value %></td> <% end %>

    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But this only runs thought the first item.value column and leaves k2 and k3 columns blank.

Are there any methods or something to help with this? I'm sure there is a more efficient and simpler way of doing this but i cant find it or think of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do a *pivot* on the `Items` table.  Try using the following query.  This should return the data in exactly the format you need, freeing you from having to do complex manipulations in your HTML layer.

```
SELECT name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN key = 'k1' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS k1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN key = 'k2' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS k2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN key = 'k3' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS k3
FROM Items
GROUP BY name
```

Here is the actual query you want, based on the new information you provided:

```
SELECT table_storing_name.name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN items.key = 'k1' THEN items.value ELSE 0 END) AS k1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN items.key = 'k2' THEN items.value ELSE 0 END) AS k2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN items.key = 'k3' THEN items.value ELSE 0 END) AS k3
FROM "table_storing_name" INNER JOIN "items"
    ON "items"."table_storing_name_id" = "table_storing_name"."id"
WHERE "table_storing_name"."category_id" = 5
GROUP BY table_storing_name.name
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't heard pivots before. One problem. To add some complexity the items table is from a join, the 'name' column is from a table we'll call table_storing_name. here is the query `SELECT table_storing_name.name, items.key, items.value 
FROM "table_storing_name" 
INNER JOIN "items" 
ON "items"."table_storing_name_id" = "table_storing_name"."id" 
WHERE "table_storing_name"."category_id" = 5` could pivots fit in with this?

Comment: I'll try to update my question, but I will leave the first on there as well because it answers your original problem.

Comment: Thanks. sorry for throwing a spanner in the works, i didn't think of doing it through SQL. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: SQL is the place to do such data manipulations because it was designed for this purpose.